# TERRAFORM CRASH | when I run terraform plan

Tags: terraform

I am running Terraform v0.12.12 and trying to deploy Azure services

> Terraform crashed! This is always indicative of a bug within Terraform.
>
> A crash log has been placed at "crash.log" relative to your current
> working directory. It would be immensely helpful if you could please
> report the crash with Terraform[1](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues) so that we can fix this.
>
> When reporting bugs, please include your terraform version. That
> information is available on the first line of crash.log. You can also
> get it by running 'terraform --version' on the command line.

Facing this issue since long. My work got delayed.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: report on github and try to use a new version

Comment: Well - what did you find in the `crash.log` log file ??

Comment: Question only talks about the problem and does not show any research effort to solve the issue